# camera_info_manager error: type argument given to delete

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I downloaded the image_common package from https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common and tried to build. The problem is, it fails with

```
Errors     << camera_info_manager:make /home/.../catkin/Catkin_test/logs/camera_info_manager/build.make.002.log                            
In file included from /usr/src/gtest/src/gtest-all.cc:42:0:
/usr/src/gtest/src/gtest.cc: In destructor ‘virtual testing::Test::~Test()’:
/usr/src/gtest/src/gtest.cc:1897:10: error: type ‘const class testing::internal::scoped_ptr<testing::internal::GTestFlagSaver>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
   delete gtest_flag_saver_;
          ^
/usr/src/gtest/src/gtest.cc: At global scope:
/usr/src/gtest/src/gtest.cc:2177:1: error: prototype for ‘testing::TestInfo::TestInfo(const string&, const string&, const char*, const char*, testing::internal::TypeId, testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)’ does not match any in class ‘testing::TestInfo’
 TestInfo::TestInfo(const std::string& a_test_case_name,
 ^
```

Unfortunately I can't interpret the error, since I don't have experience with google tests. Can anyone help?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298017/camera_info_manager-error:-type-argument-given-to-delete/) by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you please first clarify why you can't install the Kinetic binaries (ie: `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-image-common`)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-07-20**:
Good question, obviously I didn't knew that it was available, I did only check here: http://wiki.ros.org/image_common and started downloading it. Therefore the question is of course obsolete.
Is there a list which of the packages are available in the packages and which not?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-20**:
Checking the wiki page like you did, there is a green `released` badge at the top of the page. That would be one indication something is installable using `apt`.

Another would be to check the [status pages](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page) for your release.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-20**:
In general: installing pkgs using the released binaries is **always** prefered, so try that first.

Only in a few special cases would a build from sources be attempted:

1. no release available
2. you want to develop the pkg itself
3. you need a build of a specific version